# How to auto-start PVA chat conversation with Omnichannel for Customer Service Dynamics 365?

Tags: dynamics-crm, velo, power-virtual-agents

1. Omnichannel for MS Dynamics Customer Service is installed and functioning.
2. MS Power Virtual Agent (PVA) composed with live agent hand-off to Omnichannel is functioning.
3. Embed of the Omnichannel widget's script URL in portal website is functioning. When the portal page loads, the Omnichannel widget is displayed and works as expected when selected, starting the PVA conversation.
4. Embed script:
   id="Microsoft_Omnichannel_LCWidget" src="https://oc-cdn-ocprod.azureedge.net/livechatwidget/scripts/LiveChatBootstrapper.js" data-app-id=[my data app id] data-lcw-version="prod" data-org-id=[my data org id] data-org-url=[my data org url] data-enable-lcw-autofill="true" data-hide-minimize-button="true" data-suggested-action-layout="stacked" data-custom-close-button-text="End Chat"

Desired behavior: When the portal page referencing the script loads, I also want to immediately start the chat conversation when the bot loads. My intention is to use this method to display the conversation in a Wix.com lightbox which is bound to a "HELP" button on the master page.

Must this be configured in the PVA or the Omnichannel's script invocation? Or elsewhere? The script supports various "data tags", such as the 'data-hide-minimize-button="true"' seen above. Unfortunately, I can find no data tag for auto-start.

PVA also supports the ability to automatically start the bot using a custom canvas. Is this the approach I should take? Will it work when used in this context?

Answer (score 0):

you're probably talking about the "proactive chat".

Something like:

```
<!-- Code to show proactive chat invite after visitor has spend given time on the webpage -->
<script id="Proactivechattrigger">
    // Wait for Chat widget to load completely
    window.addEventListener("lcw:ready", function handleLivechatReadyEvent(){
        var timeToWaitBeforeOfferingProactiveChatInMilliseconds = 20000;//time to wait before Offering proactive chat to webpage visitor
        // Setting context variables
        Microsoft.Omnichannel.LiveChatWidget.SDK.setContextProvider(function contextProvider(){
            return {
                'Proactive Chat':{'value':'True','isDisplayable':true},
                'Time On Page':{'value': timeToWaitBeforeOfferingProactiveChatInMilliseconds ,'isDisplayable':true},
                'Page URL':{'value': window.location.href,'isDisplayable':true},
            };
        });
        
        //Display proactive chat invite after 'timeToWaitBeforeOfferingProactiveChatInMilliseconds' milliseconds
        setTimeout(function(){
            Microsoft.Omnichannel.LiveChatWidget.SDK.startProactiveChat({message: "Hi! Just checking in to see if I can help answer any questions you may have."}, false)
        },timeToWaitBeforeOfferingProactiveChatInMilliseconds);
    });
</script>
```

Check more here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-service/administer/proactive-chat

And samples/scenarios:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-service/develop/start-proactive-chat